# Connection Pool error LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

In Our project I have used LINQ to SQL for every kind of database interaction. Now from what I know , When I create and use DataContext object : it opens the connection , crates a transaction , perform the query and closes the connection.

Every now and then we are getting Connection pool error on our services and Server.

" The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached. "

Any idea ? Am I completely off here ? Is this related to SQL Server itself ?

We are using LINQ , .Net 3.5 and Sql Server 2008

NOTE: NO DATAREADER IS BEING USED ANYWHERE IN SYSTEM.

Thanks

Comment: Does your application have a bunch of users creating potentially long-executing queries? If you don't have a problem with your application closing connections correctly, then this may be a loading issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See here:

[When should I dispose of a data context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389822/when-should-i-dispose-of-a-data-context)

I'm quoting Jon Skeet quoting someone else here, but it was a surprise to me as well, since we ran into a similar issue.

> The logic that automatically closes
>   the DataContext connection can be
>   tricked into leaving the connection
>   open. The DataContext relies on the
>   application code enumerating all
>   results of a query since getting to
>   the end of a resultset triggers the
>   connection to close. If the
>   application uses IEnumerable's
>   MoveNext method instead of a foreach
>   statement in C# or VB, you can exit
>   the enumeration prematurely. If your
>   application experiences problems with
>   connections not closing and you
>   suspect the automatic closing behavior
>   is not working you can use the Dispose
>   pattern as a work around.

Basically, the mechanics of how the datacontext closes itself aren't bulletproof. I've since taken to closing it manually, which fixed our problem.