# Use of the using and DBContext

Tags: c#

I am making sure to fully understand this following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var person = new Person {FirstName = "Nadege", 
    LastName = "Deroussen", BirthDate = DateTime.Now};
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        context.Persons.Add(person);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    Console.Write("Person saved !");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As you can see, using is follow by {}, Correct me if I am wrong, does it means the the context would be closed after the {} ? a DBContext should it be closed everytime such as this ?

Cheers all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Correct me if I am wrong, does it means the the context would be closed after the {} ?

It would be disposed, yes. Your code is effectively:

```
var context = new MyContext();
try
{
    context.Persons.Add(person);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
finally
{
    context.Dispose();
}
```

> a DBContext should it be closed everytime such as this ?

Assuming this is LINQ to SQL, [you don't actually *need* to dispose of the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389822/when-should-i-dispose-of-a-data-context). However, in general it's a good idea to dispose of anything which implements `IDisposable` - unless you actually *know* that you don't need to. (Basically there are some situations where the implementation of `IDisposable` is an inconvenient side-effect of something else.) Even in this case, I would continue to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `DbContext` will be closed. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 1):

MyContext is derived from DBContext which derives from Disposable. You need to dispose your object when you are no longer using it. Using helps in this. You don't need to call context.Dispose() as using will call it itself.

It is good to use using as context is no valid after using block. If you don't use this and go for context.Dispose() and after then you call context, then exception will come. So it helps in better code management.

Comment: It's not scoping - it's disposal. Without the first sentence your answer is okay, but the first part is misleading.

Comment: I have written about disposal as well.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said that without the first sentence it's okay. I'm suggesting that you remove the first sentence.

Comment: `{}` define the scope, not the `using` directive per-se. `for` works in the same way.